# Generic method in C# accepting string or Guid as input

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, guid

I am struggling figuring out how to write a C# generic method that takes `string` or `Guid` indifferently as input parameters.
`Guid` turns out is a struct, so this makes thing a bit more complicated.

Code is:

```
public interface IBaseList<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

This generic BaseList interface is used to create similar entities: every entity has `Guid` primary key, except for a single entity that uses `string` primary key. Now, I am trying to create a method that leverage IBaseList and let me retrieve entities by using their primary key, irrespectively of its type (`string` or `Guid`).

Code so far:

```
private T FindItem<T, S>(S id) where T : class, IBaseList<S> where S : class
{
    return Set<T>().Local.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id) ?? Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
}

private T UpdateExistingItem<T, S>(T currentItem, S id) where T : class, IBaseList<S> where S : class
{
    var existingItem = FindItem<T, S>(id);
    if (existingItem != null)
    {
        Entry(existingItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(currentItem);
        return Entry(existingItem).Entity;
    };
    return currentItem;
```

This works flawlessly when calling the method with `string` type

```
MyStringObject o = UpdateExistingItem<MyStringObject, string>(myStringObject, idToCheck);
```

But when I try to do the same using `Guid` like this

```
MyGuidObject o = UpdateExistingItem<MyGuidObject, Guid>(myGuidObject, idToCheck);
```

I get the following

```
The type 'Guid' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'S' in the generic type or method 'MyContext.UpdateExistingItem<T, S>(T, S)'
```

I tried to use `where S : struct` but when I do it I get another error

```
CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'S' and 'S'
```

I have run out of ideas and didn't find much on SO, except for similar questions where the constraint was on the return value, not on the input parameter.

Comment: Side note: you really don't want `==` in your code as `object.operator ==` used in your code does not do what you probably think it does (it looks like you expect it to compare strings for string equality, not just having the same reference)

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need the class constraint on T, you don't actually care if the id field is a class or struct;

```cs
private T FindItem<T, S>(S id) where T : class, IBaseList<S>
private T UpdateExistingItem<T, S>(T currentItem, S id) where T : class, IBaseList<S>
```

Comment: unfortunately I still get `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'S' and 'S'` when setting constraints as per your answer

Comment: You can use `EqualityComparer<S>.Default.Equals(x, y);` without knowing if the type is a struct or class.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get the following error  
  
`The type 'Guid' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'S' in the generic type or method 'context.UpdateExistingItem<T, S>(T, S)`  
when calling `UpdateExistingItem<Object, Guid>(object, id)`.  
  
When calling `UpdateExistingItem<Object, string>(object, id)` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IEquatable<>

```
public interface IBaseList<T>
where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

then you can use it with Equals operator